# Using while statement inside a for loop

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have a problem with the looping of my code.

From the data which can be found here in my `listview` control:

[image]

I wanted to get the id's of every record in my `listview` control. through searching for the record using an SQL query..

Let's say `username="asd"` `password="1234"` which is `id` number `1` in my `table1`

`username="dfg"` `password="1234"` which is `id` number `2` on the same `table1`

here is a screenshot of my `table1`:

[image]

The problem is, the id's that I'm saving is not the right one . . . see this image:

[image]

The second `id` which needs to be saved in my `table2` needs to be `2` since `username="dfg"` 's `id` is number `2`

The correct data that needs to be saved would look like this...

[image]

This is the code that I've constructed so far ..

```
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= listView1.Items.Count - 1; cnt++)
        {
            string v1 = listView1.Items[cnt].SubItems[1].Text;
            string v2 = listView1.Items[cnt].SubItems[2].Text;

            //////Search for the Id of the current row value
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from account where u = @v1 AND p = @v2 ", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@v1", v1.Trim()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@v2", v2.Trim()));
            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                iid = reader.GetString("aid");          
            }
            conn.Close();

            ////////Save the retrieved Id in another table
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("insert into csvsave(aid)values(@id)", conn);
            cd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", iid));
            cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();


        }
```

Thanks to those people who are willing to help...

Comment: your iid will always have last value of `reader.GetString("aid");`

Comment: It seems like you want to either collect a `List<T>` of `iid`s, or call your `insert` *within* the `while` loop. Right now, CodingDefined is right. It'll only ever store one value, and that makes the `while` loop pretty useless.

Comment: How do I store the Id of the first row value then save it into the database? then move on to the next Row and search again the Id and then save it again? I'm kind of lost on that part...

Comment: @JustinAizengard write `MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("insert into csvsave(aid)values(@id)", conn); cd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", iid)); cd.ExecuteNonQuery();` inside your while loop

Comment: @CodingDefined I've tried it already but the desired output is not met .. .

Comment: @JustinAizengard what is the output when it's being added inside while loop?

Comment: @CodingDefined Just one record is saved in the table
only aid = "1" it won't proceed to the next row of the listview control...

Comment: @JustinAizengard you need to debug the code and let us know the values of v1, v2 and reader( or iid) in each iteration.

Comment: first row: v1 = "asd" v2 = "1234" iid = "1" -> from database

second row: v1 = "dfg" v2 = "1234" iid = "2" -> from database

my code won't retrieve the second iid . . . @CodingDefined

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of that `while` loop at all?  If there's only one record then you don't need a loop and if there's more than one then you're always going to end up using the last one anyway.  If there's any doubt that there will be a match then test the `HasRows` property of the data reader and don;t do anything else if it's `false`.  If there will always be a match then just use that one match.

Also, what's the point of searching by password?  Surely the user name is unique so why not just search by that?  Why do you even know users passwords?

Comment: That's just my dummy program ... the real information that I'm going to search is The "First Name" and "Last Name" of a certain individual since the values came from a csv file imported into the listview control

Comment: You should have said that.  Changing things to simplify is one thing but I don't see how changing two fields to two other fields helps.  Anyway, what do you want to do if you get more than one match for the name?

Comment: ahh wait... haven't thought about that ... ahh yes... i could try and search the value for the student ID which has a pattern of 000-0000-0000 . . . student Id is unique